# How to measure IO/disk usage of a program

Tags: monitoring

I am looking for a way to get **total** disk access of a program, ideally something like time(.) command that reports back disk read/write of the program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:

```
/usr/bin/time -v program args
```

will return number of blocks read and written to disk by the rpogram.

Answer (score 1):

Here, use this:

```
sudo iotop -p <process_id>
```